# Problem of multiplication of big (sparse) matrix with numpy (python)

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, numpy

I wanted to multiply two simple (big and sparse) matrix with numpy. And I saw that the calculation fails when matrices are too big.

If i take $X$ a random vector (size $n$). With pandas, I transformed this vector with `get_dummies` and I obtain a matrix $M$. One can verify that $M^\top \cdot M$ is a diagonal matrix and the trace is equal to $n$. When I do it on numpy, it doesn't work for $n>2000$. The code is below :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11111)


n_points = 5000
X = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=1,high=10,size=(n_points)))
X_bis = pd.get_dummies(X.astype('int').astype('str')).values
print(np.sum(np.sum(np.matmul(X_bis.T,X_bis))))
```

I tried with `scipy.sparse` but it didn't work either. Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce any error, even for ``n_points = 1000000``.

Comment: "It didn't work" / "the calculation fails" are not very helpful sentences; it's like going to the doctor and saying only "I'm not feeling well". What are your symptoms? Do you get an error message? Could you add more detail?

Comment: When I check: `np.sum(np.sum(np.matmul(X_bis.T, X_bis))) == n_points`, for `n_points <2000`, I get `True` and `False` if `n_points> 2000` (I tried on Jupyter or directly on a terminal, on two different computers, and I get the same problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using integers that are not big enough to represent your data. See the following snippet that solves your issue.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(11111)
n_points = 50000
X = pd.Series(np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(n_points)))
X_bis = pd.get_dummies(X, dtype=np.uint64).values
print(np.sum(X_bis.T @ X_bis))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As proposed, by changing the type of the matrix, it works well